# Integral convergence of (-1) floor

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
does this integral converge? $\int _0^\infty (-1)^{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor}dx$

**Thoughts**:
We tried using Cauchy to prove divergence. We don't know if that's true or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$k\le x^2<k+1\iff \sqrt k\le x<\sqrt{k+1}$$
so
$$\int_0^\infty(-1)^{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{\sqrt{k}}^{\sqrt{k+1}}(-1)^kdx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k}$$
and the last sum is convergent by Leibniz theorem.

Comment: Very very nice.